# Autoit does not find classname and div?

Tags: html, autoit

Hello anyone can help me with what code to use to make AutoIT click this button which is on the image. It is included in the DIV class.
[image]

I'm currently trying to use code

```
Func folder () Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "foldersTreeActionButtons") For $oInput In $oInputs If $oInput.classname == "button smallButton treeAddFolder" Then _IEAction($oInput, "click") Next EndFunc
```

But unfortunately it does not work. Please help

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry for untrusted tag